# Receiving Error ID in Debug for Flow

Tags: workflow, error, leads, gack

I have a record triggered flow on the lead object. The flow is supposed to realize that one step in the process has been completed, updating a field and sending an automated email. User asked if this was completed as he noticed the field was blank. I attempted to debug the flow and received this: Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 558823363-225535 (-1298541144).
As you can imagine, this isn't helpful. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide exact details about your Flow (screenshots?!) and describe exactly,  how you reproduced the error. As such it is very hard to provide any good advice.

Comment: Flow exceptions should send an email with complete diagnostic details -- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_troubleshoot_error_email.htm&type=5

Comment: Based on salesforce backend logs, the stacktraceId (-1298541144) points to java.lang.NullPointerException